# How To Disable A Select Collider

Tags: unity, c#

I have a character with 2 2D Colliders, one for the head, and one for the feet, How do I Disable only the Head Collider in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a script to the Character game object with two public variables:

```
public Collider2d headCollider;
public Collider2d feetCollider;
```

Then go back to the Unity editor and open the Character game object in the inspector. You should now see two slots in the script component named "Head Collider" and "Feet Collider". Drag the two colliders from the hierarchy window into these slots.

You can now switch these two colliders on and off from the same script with `headCollider.enabled = true;` or `headCollider.enabled = false;`.